# Manifest: property 'start_url' ignored, should be same origin as document

Tags: javascript, html, json, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I was just building a static HTML page & I wanted to make it installable.

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "YYY",
    "short_name": "YYY",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "android-chrome-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ],
    "theme_color": "#ffffff",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "display": "standalone",
    "start_url":"index.html"
}
```

#### index.html

```
<head>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="https://xxx.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="imageits-not-the-real-one/png" href="https://xxx.png"
        sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="imageits-not-the-real-one/png"  href="https://xxx.png"
        sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="manifest"  href="https://my-manifest-its-not-the-real-one.json">
   ..
```

#### Project structure

[image]

#### Error

Manifest: property 'start_url' ignored, should be same origin as document.

Comment: Wait! Are you linking it as `https://manifest.json` ?

Comment: No of course it's false.

Comment: Did you try using a `/` in the URL, like `/index.html` ?

Comment: Yeah. It didn't work :(

Comment: Are you working on local server or just using `file:///` to access the HTML document on your PC?

Comment: I m deploying ghpage

Comment: Hey, wait. Is your manifest inside the 'original' folder?

Comment: Could you please share the link to the actual live deployment, hosting on GitHub Pages?

Answer (score 9):

Bit late to the party but my site will ONLY accept the full URL with HTTPS enabled

I had this:
http://example.com/

but I had to use: https://example.com/

otherwise I was getting the

```
Manifest: property 'start_url' ignored error, should be same origin as document.
```

Comment: Hi, i have same error but my url also https. But manifest link different my from origin url.

Answer (score 2):

I had not faced this issue until today when I set up a website for a friend on his web host (MyDomain.com).

In this case, the problem was solved by changing...

```
"start_url": "https://[website].com/"
```

to...

```
"start_url": "https://www.[website].com/"
```

Comment: "www." is technically a subdomain and when it comes to PWA it is considered a different "origin" than the domain itself.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this means your site is serving a manifest file with a URL that does not match what your browser is using to connect.  The path to this file is specified in the `<head></head>` of your pages:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="manifest" href="/icons/site.webmanifest" />
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Using the path from your `.html` pages, locate the file, open it, and change the `start_url` property to the base URL that you are using to connect from your browser to the site.  In the example below, this is pointing to `localhost:3000`:

```json
{
  "name": "My Cool Site",
  "short_name": "coolsite",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "/icons/android-chrome-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "start_url": "http://localhost:3000",
  "display": "standalone"
}
```

Of course, this URL is environment specific.  More than likely this will be different for you when developing locally compared to when you launch the site publicly.